# Pattern matching an expression in the head of a function

Tags: erlang

Why can't you do this:

```
r() ->
     10.

result(r()) ->
    match;
result(_) ->
    no_match.
```

Error: illegal pattern.

Comment: pattern is compile-time, the result of function call is runtime. There is no `constexpr` function from C++ in Erlang.

Comment: I am curious to know what is the expected behavior, and what is the use case of this attempt

Comment: If what you want is to define a constant, then you can use a macro: `-define(R, 10).`. Then you would use it like: `result(?R) -> match; result(_) -> no_match.`

Answer (score 0):

The Erlang reference manual gives some more information on why this is not possible. 
[It specifies that](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html#id78215)

> Each argument is a pattern.

[Additionally](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80283),

> A pattern has the same structure as a term but can contain unbound variables.

[And it defines a term as](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html)

> A piece of data of any data type is called a term.

So in conclusion: A function call is not a term and thus not a pattern. As it is not a pattern, it cannot be used in a pattern match, and hence not in a function clause.

Comment: That's a clever argument, but all function calls are replaced by their return values in your code, and the return value of a function call *is* a term. So if erlang evaluated the expressions first, then subsequently did the pattern matching, my code would conform to the definitions you posted, so I think the better answer is that pattern matching is done first, then the expressions are evaluated.  I think the descriptions you posted just boil down to the rule that a pattern cannot contain an expression, e.g. `Y=2, {X, Y+1} = {hello, 3}.` => illegal pattern. But I knew that.

Comment: @7stud: Yes, you are right. Note however, that certain expressions are allowed in patterns, see http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80283. `++` for string prefixes is allowed, as well as numeric or bitwise operators involving constants. In that case, expression evaluation happens before pattern matching, turning the whole thing up-side-down again.